# Proving the horizontal distribution is not involutive

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. I'm stuck at a problem assigned by our professor.

**The problem is:**

Let $D$ be the distribution on $\mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ spanned by $V$, where
$$V:\mathbb{S}^3\rightarrow T~\mathbb{S}^3,(z_0,z_1)=z\mapsto{\rm i}z$$
is a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{S}^3$ under the isomorphism $T_z\mathbb{C}^2\cong\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $D^\bot$ denote the orthogonal complement bundle of $D$, then $D^\bot$ is a smooth distribution on $\mathbb{S}^3$ of rank $2$. Show that $D^\bot$ is not involutive.

**Here is my attempt about this problem:**

Obviously, the unit circles $\{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta}z:\theta\in\mathbb{R}\}$ in $\mathbb{S}^3$ are the integral manifolds of $D$, where $z=(z_0,z_1)\in\mathbb{S}^3$. Moreover, they are also the fibers of Hopf fibration
$$\pi:\mathbb{S}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2,(z_0,z_1)\mapsto(|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2,2z_0\bar{z_1}).$$
Note that $\pi$ is a smooth map with constant rank. Therefore, ${\rm Ker}~d\pi_z=D_z$ for each $z\in\mathbb{S}^3$.

Let $\iota:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{B}^3}$ be the inclusion map, $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^2),p\in\mathbb{S}^2,v\in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$. According to extension lemma for smooth functions, there exists $\widetilde{f}\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\mathbb{B}^3})$, such that $\left.\widetilde{f}\right|_{\mathbb{S}^2}=f$ and ${\rm supp}~\widetilde{f}\subset\overline{\mathbb{B}^3}$. Then $f=\widetilde{f}\circ\iota$, hence $v(f)=v(\widetilde{f}\circ\iota)=d\iota_p(v)(\widetilde{f})$.

I think we can prove that $D^\bot$ is not involutive by showing that there exist smooth global sections $X,Y$ of $D^\bot$, such that $[X,Y]_z\in{\rm Ker}~d\pi_z=D_z$ for some $z\in\mathbb{S}^3$. I think I'm very close to the answer, but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: consider the 1-form $(z,v) \in TS^3 \mapsto \langle iz,v\rangle$ and show that $\theta\wedge d\theta \neq 0$.

Comment: @Didier The 1-form you mentioned is a local defining form for $D^\bot$ and its exterior derivative does not annihilate $D^\bot$. Therefore, $D^\bot$ is not involutive, right?

Comment: It is a global form on $S^3$ with $\ker \theta = D^{\perp}$. My point is that $d \theta$ will be non-degenerate on $\ker \theta$, and for $X$ and $Y$ tangent to $D^{\perp}$, $d\theta (X,Y) = - \theta ([X,Y])$. This will prove non-integrability

Comment: @Didier Got it! I have understood your idea and I will have a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider the $1$-form $\alpha$ on $\Bbb C^2 \simeq \Bbb R^4$ defined by
$
\alpha_z(v) = \langle iz,v\rangle.
$
In global coordinates $(z^1,z^2) = (x^1,y^1,x^2,y^2)$, it is given by
$
\alpha = \sum_{j=1}^2 x^jdy^j - y^jdx^j.
$
We have
$
d\alpha = 2\sum_{j=1}^2 dx^j\wedge dy^j,
$
so that you can check that
$
(\alpha \wedge d\alpha)_z(u,v,w) = 2\det(z,u,v,w).
$
Consider $\iota \colon S^3\to \Bbb C^2$ the inclusion and define $\theta=\iota^*\alpha$.
Then $\theta\wedge d\theta = \iota^*(\alpha\wedge d\alpha)$ is a volume form on $S^3$.
By construction, $D^{\perp}=\ker \theta$.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be a local frame of $D^{\perp}$.
Then $\{V,X,Y\}$ is a frame of $S^3$, and
$
\theta\wedge d\theta (V,X,Y) \neq 0.
$
You can check that $d\theta(X,Y) = -\theta([X,Y])$, and that
$$
(\theta\wedge d\theta) (V,X,Y) = \theta(V) d\theta(X,Y) = -\theta([X,Y]),
$$
so that $[X,Y] \notin \ker \theta$. It follows that $[X,Y]$ is not tangent to $D^{\perp}$, and that $D^{\perp}$ is not involutive.